# css: css tag not working in td element

Tags: css

I am having trouble doing something that should be simple, styling a td tag for a table used for a monthly calendar.

The monthly calendar has days across the top.  I want to set the font of days and also the width of the columns.  However, the following seemlingly straightforward code is not working.  I think I must be missing something obvious.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvGZq/) and code:

html

```
<table><tr><td class="dayhead">Monday</td>
    <td class="dayhead">Tuesday</td>
    <td class="dayhead">Wednesday</td>
    <td class="dayhead">Thursday</td>
    <td class="dayhead">Friday</td>
    <td class="dayhead">Saturday</td>
     <td class="dayhead">Sunday</td>
</tr></table>
```

css

```
td.dayhead {
         font-size:14;
    width:70px;
    column-width:70px;
    padding:5px; 
    -moz-column-width:70px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-width:70px; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Would appreciate any suggestions about what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, now am not understanding why you need these properties? As they are not widely supported yet, especially IE will be the game spoiler for you

```
column-width:70px;
-moz-column-width:70px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-width:70px; /* Safari and Chrome */
```

If you need fixed width columns, use `table-layout: fixed;` and assign some `fixed` width to your table like this, now your columns won't have flexible widths

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 500px
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vvGZq/2/)

Also on your `font-size` property, you are not using any `unit` and hence it is not applying

---

If you are interested to re factor your markup, usinf CSS `nth-of-type()` will help you

```
table tr:nth-of-type(1) td {
   /* Styles */
}
```

This way you don't have to use classes on each cell

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vvGZq/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified the units in `font-size`.
It should be something like `font-size:14px;`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
font-size:14px
```

instead of

```
font-size:14
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `font-size` lacks a unit e.g.

`font-size: 14px;`

Your `column-width` properties are being applied successfully. Although it is merely a hint to the browser as to the optimum width of a column and won't implicitly size the column.